# How to solve and ODE to find its solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation

Salutations, I have a problem when I approach this ODE:

$$\left(\frac{y}{y'}\right)^2+y^2=b^2\left(x-\frac{y}{y'}\right)^2$$
I have done a series of steps as I show in these document:
[My Procedure](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ht4xxUlm7vXqg4S5-wirKwm7vTESU3mU/view?usp=sharing)

But I'm not convinced that those were the correct steps neither solutions were adequated, and my question is:
How would be the mathematical steps to apply to find the correct solution of the ODE?

So, I would like any guidance or starting steps or explanations to find the solution of this interesting problem.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Please use Latex to write your work. Pictures are not ideal.

Comment: The last step in your first image doesn't make sense. Everything is wrong from there.

Comment: Surely Mr. Dylan, that's why I'm confused in my procedure, this is first time that I see an ODE like this. So, what do you suggest? any help and suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your commentaries, after this time I approached the problem again and I realized I had a mistake with a sign. So, I share my proposal solution in this link: [Proposal solution](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13kIlVTCUfbkCVpfjzzZtQe8nwt8SrsOT/view?usp=sharing). Thanks for your attention.